# How to solve integral in Matlab having an upper limit set as the sine function?

Tags: matlab, math, numerical-integration, calculus

I am getting error in executing the code below for calculating one simple integral in  matlab.  The code is given below.

```
%Parameter Innitizlation

epsilon0=8.85*10^-12;
d_mos=6*10^-9;
epsilon_mos=5*epsilon0;
d_g=30*10^-9;
epsilon_g=19*epsilon0;
vt=-2;
e=1.6*10^-19;
n=[];
i=1;
t2=[];
u=60; % cm^2/v*S
h=1.05*10^-34;  % ev*s


%Capacitor Calaculation
c_g=(epsilon_g/d_g);
c_mos=(epsilon_mos/d_mos);
c_t=1/((1/c_g)+(1/c_mos));


%Input Voltage 
t = 0:0.2:10;
vg = 5*sin(t);

%Surface Voltage
fun=1-(c_t/c_g);
vs = integral(fun,0,vg);

figure 
plot(t,vs)
title('vs vs time')
```

***Error***

The error I am getting is 
"??? Undefined function or method 'integral' for input arguments of type 'double'.

Error in ==> MIT at 29
vs = integral(fun,0,vg);""

Comment: Your variable `fun` is a double vector, not a function handle. First input of integral must be a function handle.

Comment: @Daniel..What kind be the possible solution ,please.

Comment: I don't know the correct solution because I don't know what function you are trying to implement.

Comment: Are you trying to integrate a constant fun from 0 to a range of vg? Or are you trying to integrate a sine wave (5*sin t) from 0 to a constant fun?

Comment: @user1543042....I am trying to integrate the constant function from 0 to vg where vg is a sine function in tike itself.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Reading your title again it sounds like you want to integrate the constant from 0 to different bounds. So there were two things wrong:

1. You're function wasn't a function just a double, to fix this change make `fun` an anonymous function like this

   ```
   fun=@(t) (1-(c_t/c_g))*ones(size(t));
   ```

   The `ones(size(t))` just makes it so that there is an output for each input.
2. You need to have a single upper and lower bound for integral, to fix this stick your integral in an `arrayfun`, like this:

   ```
   vs = arrayfun(@(xu) integral(fun,0,xu), vg);
   ```

   For more information on [`arrayfun`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/arrayfun.html).

With the entire code here

```
epsilon0=8.85*10^-12;
d_mos=6*10^-9;
epsilon_mos=5*epsilon0;
d_g=30*10^-9;
epsilon_g=19*epsilon0;
vt=-2;
e=1.6*10^-19;
n=[];
i=1;
t2=[];
u=60; % cm^2/v*S
h=1.05*10^-34;  % ev*s


%Capacitor Calaculation
c_g=(epsilon_g/d_g);
c_mos=(epsilon_mos/d_mos);
c_t=1/((1/c_g)+(1/c_mos));


%Input Voltage 
t = 0:0.2:10;
vg = 5*sin(t);

%Surface Voltage
fun=@(t) (1-(c_t/c_g))*ones(size(t));
vs = arrayfun(@(xu) integral(fun,0,xu), vg);

figure 
plot(t,vs)
title('vs vs time')
```

Comment: @user1543043  I exucuted the code according to your kind instructions but still getting an  error                                                                           " ??? Undefined function or method 'integral' for input arguments of type
'function_handle'.

Error in ==> @(xu)integral(fun,0,xu)                                                                 Thanks for your help. can you kindly help me rectifying this error.

Comment: I exucuted the code according to your kind instructions but still getting an error " ??? Undefined function or method 'integral' for input arguments of type 'function_handle'. Error in ==> @(xu)integral(fun,0,xu) Thanks for your help. can you kindly help me rectifying this error.

Comment: What version of Matlab are you using because it works on my machine.

Comment: My version of matlab is 7.12.0 ( R2011a)

Comment: That's your problem `integral` was introduced in R2012a (see the bottom of the page http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/integral.html).

Comment: Thanks alot. Your help is appreciated.